# Submodule Definition and Tensor Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

In Hungerford's Algebra, submodule is defined as follows:

> Let $R$ be a ring, $A$ an $R$-module and $B$ a nonempty subset of $A$.
>   $B$ is a submodule of $A$ provided that $B$ is an additive subgroup of
>   $A$ and $rb \in B$ for all $r \in R$

Now, let $M$ and $N$ be $\mathbb{Z}$-module and $H$ be a subset of $N$. Is it possible that $M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} H$ to be a submodule of $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} N$ even if $H$ is not a subgroup of $N$ but $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H$ is additive subgroup of $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} N$ and $rt \in M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H$ for all $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $t \in M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H$?

Comment: What does $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z}H$ mean if $H$ is not an abelian group?

Comment: I believe $M$ and $H$ will fail to form a tensor product as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module if $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module and $H$ is just a subset and not an additive abelian group.

Comment: What if $H$ is a multiplicative abelian group but not additive? For example, $H = \{1\}$.

Comment: Your question is completely meaningless until you say what you mean by $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H$.

Comment: Note that even when $H$ _is_ a submodule of $N$, $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H$ is not even a subset of $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} N$ unless $H=N$.  (There is a natural homomorphism $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H\to M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} N$ which is sometimes injective, and in those cases you can think of it as a submodule.)

Comment: Is there a proof to it that you can link to?